# javascript array to (16 bit) image

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I'm looking for a way to save/export data in a javascript array to an image (preferably tiff, but any lossless format is fine).  The catch is that the resulting image **must** be at least 16bit (grayscale).

I've looked all over and seen many solutions for array->image (and some for *reading* high bit-depth images such as [tiff.js](https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js/tree/master)), but none that write to file and preserve the bit depth that I need.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is your code going to run, in a browser? If so, you'll need something on the server to save the file, such as [node.js](https://nodejs.org) or [python](https://www.python.org/)...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Sorry I should have specified:  Yes, my hope was to find a solution in a browser, on the client side.  The "image data" that I'd like to export is a result of user interaction with the web app.  I'm integrating this project into a bigger website where I have no control over the server, so if this can't be done client-side, I'll have to see what sort of server side tech I have available to me...  Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, you're definitely going to need a server side solution, unless an unsigned Active-X control running in IE is ok...

Comment: yeah, Active-X in IE won't be sufficient.  Thanks for the feedback!